# Text Shadow CSS not working properly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the text shadow effect as per the example below:

[image: text shadow]

This is what I have created:

```css
.yb-shipping {
  color: #f2de4d;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(1, 96, 116, 1);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="yb-shipping">Free Shipping</div>
```

Not able to make as attached, should I try something else except text-shadow?

Please suggest

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use a blur radius, the shadow will be blurred, and that's not the intended result.
You can, however, use multiple text-shadows. So that's the solution: add several of them, all with a blur radius of 0, in different directions.

```css
.yb-shipping {
  color: #f2de4d;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: -2px -2px 0 rgba(1, 96, 116, 1),
               2px -2px 0 rgba(1, 96, 116, 1),
               -2px 2px 0 rgba(1, 96, 116, 1),
               2px 2px 0 rgba(1, 96, 116, 1),
               -3px 0 0 rgba(1, 96, 116, 1),
               3px 0 0 rgba(1, 96, 116, 1),
               0 -3px 0 rgba(1, 96, 116, 1),
               0 3px 0 rgba(1, 96, 116, 1);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="yb-shipping">Free Shipping</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can combine many shadows

```css
.yb-shipping {
  color: #f2de4d;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 
    2px 2px 2px rgba(1, 96, 116, 1),
    -2px 2px 2px rgba(1, 96, 116, 1),
    2px -2px 2px rgba(1, 96, 116, 1),
    -2px -2px 2px rgba(1, 96, 116, 1);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="yb-shipping">Free Shipping</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `-webkit-text-stroke` as below:

```
.yb-shipping {
  color: #f2de4d;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px rgba(1, 96, 116, 1);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke) says: "Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future."

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following:-

https://jsfiddle.net/enryhfz3/

If you change you text-shadow to :-

```
text-shadow:
    -1px -1px 5px rgba(1, 96, 116, 1),  
    1px -1px 5px rgba(1, 96, 116, 1),
    -1px 1px 5px rgba(1, 96, 116, 1),
    1px 1px 5px rgba(1, 96, 116, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This generator can help you make text shadow more accureate. http://css3gen.com/text-shadow/ and http://www.css3generator.in/text-shadow.html
The codes can be copy and paste directly.